# Obtain standardized factor scores for latent variables after CFA - Lavaan package in R

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I want to predict the factor scores of latent variables from CFA, and use them as independent variables in another model (not SEM). Because the latent variables don't have a measurement unit, I want to standardize them so that I can interpret them by referring to, for e.g., 1 std. dev. increase in 'visual' increases the dependent variable by 'coefficient' amount.

The predicted values after CFA - codes below - are not standardized; mean is zero but the std. dev. are not 1. I was wondering if there is a way to directly predict standardized factors scores for the latent variables, or the only way is to do it manually?

```
     library(lavaan)
     library(psych)

     df <- as.data.frame(HolzingerSwineford1939)

     model  <-'
               visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
               textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
               speed =~ x7 + x8 + x9
              '

     m1 <- sem(model = model, data = df, std.lv = T, std.ov = T)
     summary(m1, fit.measures = T, standardized = T)
    lavaan 0.6-5 ended normally after 21 iterations

      Estimator                                         ML
      Optimization method                           NLMINB
      Number of free parameters                         21

      Number of observations                           301

    Model Test User Model:

      Test statistic                                85.306
      Degrees of freedom                                24
      P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

    Model Test Baseline Model:

      Test statistic                               918.852
      Degrees of freedom                                36
      P-value                                        0.000

    User Model versus Baseline Model:

      Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.931
      Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.896

    Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

      Loglikelihood user model (H0)              -3422.624
      Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)      -3379.971

      Akaike (AIC)                                6887.248
      Bayesian (BIC)                              6965.097
      Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)         6898.497

    Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

      RMSEA                                          0.092
      90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.071
      90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.114
      P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.001

    Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

      SRMR                                           0.065

    Parameter Estimates:

      Information                                 Expected
      Information saturated (h1) model          Structured
      Standard errors                             Standard

    Latent Variables:
                       Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
      visual =~                                                             
        x1                0.771    0.069   11.127    0.000    0.771    0.772
        x2                0.423    0.066    6.429    0.000    0.423    0.424
        x3                0.580    0.066    8.817    0.000    0.580    0.581
      textual =~                                                            
        x4                0.850    0.049   17.474    0.000    0.850    0.852
        x5                0.854    0.049   17.576    0.000    0.854    0.855
        x6                0.837    0.049   17.082    0.000    0.837    0.838
      speed =~                                                              
        x7                0.569    0.064    8.903    0.000    0.569    0.570
        x8                0.722    0.065   11.090    0.000    0.722    0.723
        x9                0.664    0.064   10.305    0.000    0.664    0.665

    Covariances:
                       Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
      visual ~~                                                             
        textual           0.459    0.064    7.189    0.000    0.459    0.459
        speed             0.471    0.073    6.461    0.000    0.471    0.471
      textual ~~                                                            
        speed             0.283    0.069    4.117    0.000    0.283    0.283

    Variances:
                       Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
       .x1                0.403    0.083    4.833    0.000    0.403    0.404
       .x2                0.818    0.073   11.146    0.000    0.818    0.821
       .x3                0.660    0.071    9.317    0.000    0.660    0.662
       .x4                0.274    0.035    7.779    0.000    0.274    0.275
       .x5                0.268    0.035    7.642    0.000    0.268    0.269
       .x6                0.297    0.036    8.277    0.000    0.297    0.298
       .x7                0.673    0.069    9.823    0.000    0.673    0.676
       .x8                0.476    0.072    6.573    0.000    0.476    0.477
       .x9                0.556    0.069    8.003    0.000    0.556    0.558
        visual            1.000                               1.000    1.000
        textual           1.000                               1.000    1.000
        speed             1.000                               1.000    1.000


     head(lavPredict(m1, method = "regression"))
              visual     textual       speed
    [1,] -0.90891188 -0.13897763  0.09928941
    [2,]  0.05504481 -1.02327119  1.00971784
    [3,] -0.84635409 -1.89178562 -1.35691418
    [4,]  0.46613166  0.01867827 -0.43801243
    [5,] -0.46231174 -0.12352319  0.31370068
    [6,]  0.02585128 -1.34366688  1.14428335

     fscores <- lavPredict(m1, method = "regression")
     describe(fscores)
            vars   n mean   sd median trimmed  mad   min  max range skew kurtosis   se
    visual     1 301    0 0.85  -0.03    0.00 0.81 -2.68 2.77  5.45 0.03     0.20 0.05
    textual    2 301    0 0.94   0.01   -0.02 0.89 -2.32 2.73  5.06 0.19    -0.10 0.05
    speed      3 301    0 0.85  -0.02   -0.01 0.80 -2.73 2.69  5.42 0.14     0.38 0.05
```

Comment: did you find a solution? Would standardizing the obtained factor scores do?